# Wordpress Login Before Content

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there any way to protect my whole wordpress frontend website with a login form? I need to have a login form before somebody see any content of my website. so, if somebody goes to the url of content without be logged in he must redirect to login form until he do login. how can i do that? is there any plugin?

Comment: No plug-in's on that, You have to make your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hook to `init`

```
function my_redirect_hook()
{
    if(!is_user_logged_in())
    {
        wp_safe_redirect('url-to-you-login-form');
    }
}  
add_action('init', 'my_redirect_hook');
```

Comment: where i have to write this code? in which file?

Comment: @cosnik your theme's functions.php will do

Comment: when i go directly to example.com/about it doesnt work..how i can fix that?